# Calculating the Standard Deviation of the Sampling Distribution when using Bernoulli Sampling

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling-distribution

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of a sampling distribution when using Bernoulli sampling (where each item is given a separate, equal, non-zero probability of being included in the sample). Based on my stats textbook, to use the 1/sqrt(n) rule the sample needs to be independent and the Bernoulli sampling should fulfill that requirement. I tried doing a simulation of this though, and the Sx of the sampling distribution doesn't correlate with the 1/sqrt(n) rule, and a finite population correction is needed. Does anyone have ideas on where I might have done something wrong, or if my results are expected?

Edit: Here is the google sheet I did the calculations in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1it4j232z7zolgZJqAIIT73Swj9ny_EhkDFkQkOMHL7s/edit?usp=sharing

Edit2: The way to produce this effect would be to generate a sampling distribution at different sampling percentages, and compare the standard deviation of those results to the standard deviation from the 1/sqrt(n) rule. In the case of the spreadsheet, there is the independent sampling method, which is the one I am interested in, and the two others are to compare to other sampling methods.[image: I added an image of the graph for the Sx relative to the 1/sqrt(n) model at different sampling fractions. In this case the population was 1000.]

Comment: Maybe show us your simulation code and calculations?

Comment: I added a link to the google sheets document I used to calculate the sampling distribution at different probabilities.

Comment: Could you add it to the question rather than as a link to external resource?

Comment: Because there's no finite population in this description, it isn't plausible that such a correction would be needed.  Please present a small reproducible example of what you are doing.  No, we don't really want to decipher a spreadsheet (especially one that has no evident relationship to the question): you can include an explanation in the text of the question itself.

Comment: I added an explanation for the graph, and how it relates to the problem.